# May planning entites reference other planning entities?

Tags: optaplanner, timefold

May one planning entity reference another planning entity and depend on the other entity in score calculations?

**Example:** A `Lecture` either has a planning variable `Timeslot startTime` set, or it has a reference to another lecture, `Lecture sameStartTimeAsOtherLecture`.

When score calculation (Bavet) is performed, the conflict rule may pick up the start time from the referenced `Lecture`.

Is such setup ok?

**Reason for the question**: In my head I have assumed that incremental score calculation depends on having knowledge of what entities are changed, and I figured the setup suggested above might be problematic since the validity of a constraints of a `Lecture` may change based on updates of a different `Lecture`.

**If not ok**, is there a recommended workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you are describing will cause a score corruption. Consider the following constraint:

```
forEach(Lecture.class)
    .filter(lecture -> lecture.otherLecture().getStartTime() > ...)
    ...
```

The filter will only be re-evaluated when the outer lecture changes, but it will not be re-evaluated if only the inner lecture changes.

The solution to this problem is to clearly mark the other lecture for re-evaluation, using a `join`:

```
forEach(Lecture.class)
    .join(Lecture.class,
         Joiners.equal(Lecture::otherLecture(), Function.identity())
    .filter((lecture, otherLecture) -> otherLecture.getStartTime() > ...)
    ...
```

Comment: Interesting. My example was indeed simplified a little bit, so your "However..." part is probably what I'll have to do. What I'm planning on doing is to group `Lecture` objects in a `LectureGroup` (a static configuration). The group will have a start time (which is common to all lectures in the group) but the room assignments (also a PlanningVariable) are on lecture level, so a change in group start time, may affect room conflicts in lectures.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to do a `join` in this case, yes.

Comment: I just realized my answer was partially wrong. The solution is still the same, but I updated the answer to give the correct explanation.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I assume that it is not sufficient to `groupBy` or perform some `flattenLast` operation to include the referenced lectures in the stream? They have to be _joined_ into the stream for Timefold to understand what constraints need to be reevaluated.

Comment: This gets hard to explain. Maybe ask another question, where there will be more room for an elaborate answer?

Comment: Ok, will do! Thanks again.