# Writing constraints for nested (and dependent) planning entities

Tags: timefold

This is a follow up / updated question of [May planning entites reference other planning entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77424968/may-planning-entites-reference-other-planning-entities)

I'm working on a school schedule solver.

In order to support "groups of lectures" with a common start time (important for "break out subjects" such as language classes, where spanish, german, french must be taught at the same time for the schedule to make sense), I have now created the following structure:

```
@PlaningEntity
class LectureGroup {

    @PlanningVariable
    Timeslot timeslot;

    List<Lecture> lectures;

    // ...some other properties...
}

@PlanningEntity
class Lecture {
    @PlanningVariable
    Room room;

    int lectureLength;
    LectureGroup myLectureGroup; // LectureGroup in which this lecture is part of

    // ...some other properties...

    Timeslot getStartTime() {
        return myLectureGroup.timeslot;
    }

    Timeslot getEndTime() {
        return myLectureGroup.timeslot.plus(lectureLength);
    }
}

@PlanningSolution
class Schedule {
 
    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    List<LectureGroups> lectureGroups;

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    List<Lecture> lectures;  // always equal to flattened list of lectures from the lectureGroups

    // ...
}
```

To keep things simple, all `Lecture`s are wrapped in a `LectureGroup`, even if the `LectureGroup` only contains one lecture.

**My Question:** (which is basically very similar to my previous one)

What's the recommended way to express, in this case, a room conflict constraint? A naive solution could look like:

```
UniConstraintStream<Lecture> lecturesWithRooms = cf.forEach(Lecture.class)
        .filter(Lecture::hasRoom);

return lecturesWithRooms.join(lecturesWithRooms,
            Joiners.equals(Lecture::getRoom),
            Joiners.overlapping(Lecture::getStartTime, Lecture::getEndTime)
            Joiners.lessThan(Lecture::getLectureId))
        .penalize(...)
        .justifyWith(...)
        .asConstraint(...);
```

As I understand, updates to the `timeslot` of a `LectureGroup` will not trigger proper reevaluation.

A refined solution could be to start with...

```
UniConstraintStream<Lecture> lecturesWithRooms = cf.forEach(LectureGroup.class)
        .filter(LectureGroup::hasTimeslot)
        .flattenLast(LectureGroup::getLectures)
        .filter(Lecture::hasRoom);
```

...but then I suspect direct updates to `Lecture.room` will not trigger reevaluation.

Reading the answer to my previous question, maybe I have to use *both* variants of `lecturesWithRooms` above, and join them with `Function.identity` in order to retrigger evaluation regardless if the time (in `LectureGroup`) or the room (in `Lecture`) is updated?

Any thoughts welcome here.

---

Update: Here's my current attempt:

```
UniConstraintStream<Lecture> lecturesFromLectures =
        cf.forEachIncludingNullVars(Lecture.class);

UniConstraintStream<Lecture> lecturesFromGroups =
        cf.forEachIncludingNullVars(LectureGroup.class).flattenLast(LectureGroup::getLectures);

UniConstraintStream<Lecture> lectures = lecturesFromLectures
        .join(lecturesFromGroups, Joiners.equal(Function.identity()))
        .groupBy((l1, l2) -> l1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance considerations aside, this should work:

```
BiConstraintStream<LectureGroup, Lecture> lectures = 
    cf.forEachIncludingNullVars(LectureGroup.class)
        .join(Lecture.class, Joiners.filtering((group, lecture) -> group.contains(lecture)));
```

Comment: Ah, no need to flatten. Very concise. And I assume that I can just `.groupBy((l1, l2) -> l2)` to get a (properly reevaluating) `UniConstraintStream<Lecture>`

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Given my use case (basically multiple entities (lectures) sharing a common planning variable (start time)) do you immediately see a simpler (and possibly more efficient) way of solving this? Like, if you were to solve this, would you have taken a different approach? Perhaps something with shadow variables?

Comment: This is as simple as it gets; it's isolated in the constraints, easy to understand, easy to test. I would only start inventing different solutions if, for whatever reason, this solution didn't work.